# update multiple rows with calculated variable

Tags: php, pdo

The table_calc structure (minimized) is:

| id | value_1 | value_2 |

the number of rows is between 70 and 250 or more.

I want to update the fields in "table_calc" with values resulting from other calculations ($value_update_1 and 2, ...), values applied different to the fields in the table.

Before I used a table on the web page and from there I updated the table.
Now I want to update the values directly without having to take them in the page, as it should work.

I started to write the code below:

```
$stmt_update = $conn_bd->prepare('select * from table_calc');
$stmt_update->execute(array());
$result_stmt_update = $stmt_update->fetchAll();
foreach($result_stmt_update as $rrows_update) {
  $cal_id = $rrows_update[id];
  $cal_value_1 = $rrows_update['value_1'];
  $cal_value_2 = $rrows_update['value_2'];
}

$value_update_1 = 100.25;
$value_update_2 = 150.25;

$count_id = count($cal_id);
$stmt = $conn_bd->prepare('UPDATE table_calc SET value_1 = :value_1, value_2 = :value_2 WHERE id = :id');
$i = 0;
while($i < $count_id) {
  $stmt->bindParam(':value_1', '.$cal_value_1[$i].' * '.$value_update_2.');
  $stmt->bindParam(':value_2', '.$cal_value_2[$i].' * '.$value_update_1.');
  $stmt->bindParam(':id', $cal_id[$i]);
  $stmt->execute();
  $i++;
}
```

but it doesn't work

Can you help?

Comment: you're right, the error was evident. thk for the sugestion to use Transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can spot a few issues on your code:

- On line 8:

  ```
  $cal_id = $rrows_update[id];
                          ^^
  ```

  You need quotes there.
- On line 20, you call your variable as if it were an array, but you don't set it as such on lines 9-10.
- Again on line 20, you should bind the final value to the parameter, not leave it to be evaluated by MySQL.

So the corrected version would be:

```
$stmt_update = $conn_bd->prepare('select * from table_calc');
$stmt_update->execute(array());
$result_stmt_update = $stmt_update->fetchAll();
foreach ($result_stmt_update as $rrows_update) {
    //Added array push operators. To make them arrays.
    $cal_id[]      = $rrows_update["id"];
    $cal_value_1[] = $rrows_update['value_1'];
    $cal_value_2[] = $rrows_update['value_2'];
}

$value_update_1 = 100.25;
$value_update_2 = 150.25;

$count_id = count($cal_id);
$stmt     = $conn_bd->prepare('UPDATE table_calc SET value_1 = :value_1, value_2 = :value_2 WHERE id = :id');
$i        = 0;
while ($i < $count_id) {
    //Altered the binding so that you bind the final value.
    //Also changed to bindValue.
    $stmt->bindValue(':value_1', $cal_value_1[$i] * $value_update_2);
    $stmt->bindValue(':value_2', $cal_value_2[$i] * $value_update_1);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $cal_id[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $i++;
}
```

Also, when making batch changes to the database, you may want to use **[Transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php)**, to make sure all changes are registered as expected.

Comment: how can I make the $cal_id different for $cal_value_1 and $cal_value_2? assuming in one scenario that: $cal_id returns 1 to 7 and $cal_value_1 goes to 1 to 5 and $cal_value_w goes to 3 to 6